# Rails 4 Delete link influenced by Template JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I am using rails 4 with devise. All the Devise functionality works as expected including the "Sign Out" link given by the following piece of code:

```
= link_to "<span class= 'fa fa-power-off'></span> Sign Out".html_safe, destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

I have since installed a template and ran into some issues. The JS in the template file seems to be causing some difficulty when I place my "Sign Out" link in a dropdown on the Navbar. 
If I place the link in my normal body content, it does work. This led me to the template source code to try and figure out why this link was sending a GET request instead of a DELETE request when placed in a Template navbar dropdown. After I deleted the following piece of code, my link started working:

```
 $('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(e) {

     e.stopPropagation();
     var Target  = $(e.target);
     var TargetGroup = Target.parents('.btn-group');
     var SiblingGroup = Target.parents('.dropdown-menu').find('.btn-group');

     // closes all open multiselect menus. Creates Toggle like functionality
     if (Target.hasClass('multiselect') || Target.parent().hasClass('multiselect')) {
       SiblingGroup.removeClass('open');
       TargetGroup.addClass('open');
     }
     else { SiblingGroup.removeClass('open'); }
      e.stopPropagation();
      var Target  = $(e.target);
      var TargetGroup = Target.parents('.btn-group');
      var SiblingGroup = Target.parents('.dropdown-menu').find('.btn-group');
  });
```

When I added the remainder of the Template js files, it stops working again, so I assume that something similar is done in one of the other files. Instead of removing pieces of JS, I am trying to understand what's happening. I understand that Rails uses it's ujs to trigger a DELETE request but why is the above piece of JS code hindering Rails from doing what it's supposed to?

PS. I am not fluent in JS so this might seem simple to somebody who knows JS extremely well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `e.stopPropagation();` lines in the js code. These are likely not really needed. However, it may depend of kinds of other links in the dropdown menu. Just try to remove those two lines and check if everything works fine.